# Calculate expectation of minimum and maximum of two random variables?

Tags: probability, random, covariance

Let $X, Y$ be independent uniform in $[−1, 1]$. Find the covariance between $U = \min(X, Y )$ and $V = \max(X, Y )$

I know that 
$\operatorname{Cov}(U,V)= E\left(UV\right) - EUEV$
and I know how to calculate $EU$ and $EV$. However, I'm not sure how to calculate $E\left(UV\right)$. Since we have only two variables in this case, is it correct to reason that $UV = XY$, since if one of $X,Y$ is the max then the other is the min?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @angryavian I see. So then $E(UV)$ would be $0$ since $E(XY) = EXEY = 0 \cdot 0$?

Comment: I suspect this is going to end badly. My preferred approach is ... if you are familiar with order statistics ... to derive the joint pdf of the 1st and 2nd order stats, in a sample of size 2 (i.e. the min and the max), which makes the dependence between the min and max explicit. ... and then calculate any necessary expectations.